# PermissionsAndroid.request always returns PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED

Tags: android, react-native

I am using [PermissionsAndroid](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/permissionsandroid.html) to request a permission from user. I have used example code given there.

```
try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
    {
      'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
      'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
      'so you can take awesome pictures.'
    }
  )
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    console.log("You can use the camera")
  } else {
    console.log("Camera permission denied")
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err)
}
```

Whenever i call this method, it always show me output as "**You can use the camera**". However i have disabled that permission from app setting, but still it always show that permission as `GRANTED`

Comment: Why are you using '===' instead of '==' ?

Comment: There is an open issue about this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13097

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani That is what written there in official doc. I have given reference link also, you can check

Comment: @MotiAzu It means there is still no solution for that, right?

Comment: Run time Permission are granted in Marshmallow and above not in below Android OS.

Comment: @SagarGangawane running it in 7.0.0

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I don't really know, I'm working on an app requesting mic access on Android and it works perfectly. Since your issue and the one in github are both camera related this might mean something.

Comment: Can you check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13097#issuecomment-291547262) comment?

Answer (score 1):

You should use min targetSdkVersion as 23 given in official documentation.

[Permission Android Official Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html)

> On devices before SDK version 23, the permissions are automatically granted if they appear in the manifest, so check and request should always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the below entry is in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.retrorabbit.react-test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
```

I had this same issue in Xamarin Native just setting the properties in build.gradle isn't sufficient